# How to add WP Gutemberg's color palette classes to NextJS

Tags: wordpress, next.js, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm developing a Wordpress Headless website using NextJS.
In the blog section, I'm using Gutemberg to render text, buttons and links.

I would like to be able to assign each of these elements its own color and style using the Gutemberg color palette.

So far, I was able to get the "general style" of those elements by using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aamodtgroup/gutenberg-styles but I couldn't get the style of classes such as "has-purple-color", "has-orange-text" etc..
I'm getting the content of each post through the dangerouslySetInnerHTML method

`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content.rendered }} />`

HTML wise everything is working correctly: I can see every elements that has been added to the post content, except the custom CSS style.

I was wondering if there's a way of doing this! The idea is to allow my client to be able to customize the content of blog posts through WP Backend using the Gutemberg interface and then see the output on the NextJs frontend.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Recently, as of version 5.9, a new [Global Settings and Styles API](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/01/04/new-api-to-access-global-settings-styles/) was added to enable access to global settings and styles. This may be used to get the style of classes like "has-purple-color". The `wp_get_global_stylesheet()` merges core, theme and user data like the color presets edited via the Editor:

```php
<?php 
wp_get_global_stylesheet( $types = array() ); // Supports 'variables', 'styles', 'presets'
```

Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_global_stylesheet/

The styles color palette also exists in the database, as a `wp_global_styles` custom post type if you wish to see all the actual values:

```mysql
SELECT * from <database_name>.wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'wp_global_styles' 
AND post_name = 'wp-global-styles-<theme-slug>'; # eg: wp-global-styles-twentytwentythree
```